# Unresolved Dependency While following the Sample Code for People Api of Google

Tags: java, google-people-api

I was studying the Google People Api for Extracting Information and I was following this link:
https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/java#step_3_set_up_the_sample
But the line:

```
import com.google.api.services.people.v1.PeopleScopes;
```

is giving an unresolved error. The class is not present in the `google-api-services-people-v1-rev244-1.23.0.jar`, as I tried typing it by hand.
Does anybody have a way out of it? I am trying to find some other way to sort this out!

This Line produces a NullPointerException

```
InputStream in =      
Quickstart.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secret.json");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the documentation needs to be updated. If you check out the [javadocs](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/people/v1/java/latest/) it shows there is a `PersonServiceScopes` class, which is probably what you want.

Comment: It Worked! I faced an EOFException for GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
                new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                        HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                .setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY)
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .build();
After changing the DATA_STORE_DIR path to a folder where I had read and write access,that too god resolved as well. Thank You!